# postgres 9.6 new progress reporting facility

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Reading [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-6.html) of recent Postgres 9.6, I found this interesting new feature

> Add a generic command progress reporting facility (Vinayak Pokale,
>   Rahila Syed, Amit Langote, Robert Haas)

Further reading gave me no information on this, but [some play around](https://www.depesz.com/2016/03/09/waiting-for-9-6-add-a-generic-command-progress-reporting-facility/) article at depesz.

Of course the first what I thought - is there any history for what has been processed (and list of object to be processed - I dreamed) somewhere as well? Or this `pg_stat_get_progress_info` just shows current and have no idea of VACUUM plans and past?..

And another Question - Is there interface to consume that facility for own process (reports, data load and etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view is called [`pg_stat_progress_vacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/progress-reporting.html#PG-STAT-PROGRESS-VACUUM-VIEW); depesz must have used an older version of the patch for his article.

Currently, progress reporting is only available for `VACUUM` (and autovacuum) operations.

This feature offers no historical data, but there are other ways to get those:

- If you set `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to 0, all autovacuum operations will be reported in the server log (normally, you don't have to run `VACUUM` manually).
- The `pg_stat_all_tables` system view contains columns `last_vacuum` and `last_autovacuum` that indicate when the respective operation last ran on the table.

Comment: thank you! This is how I check tables that need vacuum atm. I thought the new feature will show us the pg_dump and maybe something else. I liked the word "generic" in release notes :) So it gave me hope for some iface to it. Anyway thanks for clarification! `progress_vacuum` sounds clearly for `vacuum`